# Scroll x with div

Tags: html, css

I want to make some slider on my own way but it seems something is bad:

I have:

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="img first"></div>
<div class="img second"></div>
<div class="img third"></div>
</div>

.slider{width: 100%; max-height: 100%; overflow: hidden;} 
//I don't want to see scrolls
.img{width: 100%; height: 100%; float: left;}
.first{background: red;}
.second{background: blue;}
.third{background: green;}
```

Basically what I want is to have this:

```
  100%     100%    100%
+-------+--------+-------+
+-------+ 
| 100%  |
|first  | second   third
+-------+
+------------------------+
```

The problem is that my divs go one under another.. Is it problem with the float: left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what your code is explaining to me above it looks like each slide of your slider is going to be an image. If so, I recommend altering your slider to the following code below:

CODE SNIPPET:

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider figure img {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}

.slider figure {
  width: 400%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: 10s slide infinite;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slide infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  16% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  49% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  82% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mxbzT3uYXxE/maxresdefault.jpg">
    <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/1af8dfed-eacb-4228-8219-8781715daa2d/115aad8d-8eee-45e4-b439-450602e843fd.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.majorspoilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/MSC6.jpg">
    <img src="http://static.srcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/franklin-richards.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Rather than having a specific DIV each time to call your `img` class, we can instead just use the actual `img` tag. Along with that, in this method I've used the `keyframes` css to control the slide images positioning.

Should you really want to control this with `div` content, you could simply wrap the images in your `div` and alter the class `.slider figure img` to `.slider figure div`to include other types of content.

I hope that this helps you in your endeavours.

Comment: This is so easy i was thinking to use javascript :D Can you describe me this keyframes I dont understan why u did that at all :D

Comment: Keyframes works on a 0% to a 100% scale. So 0% is your beginning where the 100% is your end. If you had one slide you would be highlighting just those two points in your percentage. As you can see in the CSS I provided for you as an example I have 4 slides. Those 4 slides then need to be arranged in that 0% to 100%  based how they are being slid in. The slides movement are being done in -100% groupings because my images inside the slider are taking up 25% of the space. 

For more on @keyframes rule see this link from w3c.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp